# Corda evolving of the Contract State with Signing constraint

Tags: corda

In my Corda 4.1 installation I use Signing constraint and want to add a new field "test" in my state. After adding it, and updating my cordapp when I try to query my vault I get the following error:

`"VaultQueryException - An error occurred while attempting to query the vault: Failed to deserialise group OUTPUTS_GROUP at index 0 in transaction:       Cannot construct evolution serializer for remote type sg.tradecloud.contracts.states.company.properties.Company: Mandatory property test of local type is not present in remote type. This implies the type has not evolved in a backwards compatible way. Consider making test nullable in the newer version of this type.`

What options do I have to resolve this issue? Should I make "test" nullable ? Should I do explicit state update? or there are other was I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should make the new field introduced as nullable. Corda would not be able to deserialise the older issued states unless you make the newly added fields nullable.

Comment: But anyways if I need to keep them non nullable, what is the way to do that? Explicit migration ?